# "Explicit specialization of std::iterator_traits<char *> after instantiation" (CLang)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, template-specialization

I've got some code that compiles fine under MSVC (or so say the Windows developers who sent me it), but gives an error under CLang. Having looked around I've found that CLang is indeed more strict about resolving template specializations, but I'm not sure where I should put the specializations in my case. Basically one of my files has a struct like this:

```
template<>
struct iterator_traits< char * >   // error is here
{
    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef char value_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef difference_type distance_type;
    typedef char * pointer;
    typedef char & reference;
};
```

This is within a `namespace std` block. The error message is:

```
Explicit specialization of 'std::iterator_traits<char *>' after instantiation
```

Another part of the same error message (viewed by 'expanding' the error message in Xcode) says `Implicit instantiation first required here`, and clicking on that takes me to `stl_iterator.h`, specifically this line (line 642):

```
typedef typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category
                                                         iterator_category;
```

Does anyone know what the correct thing to do would be in this case? I've seen examples involving classes but never one involving a struct.

Comment: This looks like standard library code. Are you trying to compile the MS standard library with Clang by chance?

Comment: Check that you are including the right headers for the standard library. Besides that, `struct` and `class` are almost interchangeable (the only difference is the default access specifier in `struct` is public)

Comment: @KerrekSB Specializing things from `std`, like `std::iterator_traits` for custom iterators, is pretty common (even if there are other ways, like deriving from `std::iterator`) outside of the standard library. Though it is still weird to do this for `char*` given that the standard library already has one for any `T*`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I'm pretty certain you're only allowed to specialize templates from `std` for *user-defined types*.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it seems (after reading Adam's answer). I was just making the point that this doesn't neccessarily look like standard library code.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yeah... I was confused and didn't realize that the code is the OP's own code. It all makes sense now.

Comment: @KerrekSB Looking at it, I have just realised that this is part of an MS standard library header... thanks for the spot! I guess in my case I'd better remove this and recreate the required functionality elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that you're trying to specialize a template after instantiating the generic template -- by that point in time, the compiler has already used the generic template for the instantiation, and it can't go back and use your specialization instead.  In other words, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    // Generic implementation
};

// Instantiate template by using it in any way
X<int> foo;

template<>
struct X<int>
{
    // Specialization implementation for int
};
```

The fix is to define the specialization *before* it's instantiated, so in this example, you'd move the `X<int>` specialization to before where `X<int>` is used.

Note that the STL already defines specializations of `std::iterator_trait` for pointer types, so there's no need to define your own specialization here for `char*`.  You'd typically only do that for user-defined iterator types which are not pointers.  See §24.3.1/2 of the C++03 standard:

> [The template `iterator_traits<Iterator>`] is specialized for pointers as
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct iterator_traits<T*> {
>   typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
>   typedef T value_type;
>   typedef T* pointer;
>   typedef T& reference;
>   typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
> };
> ```
>
> and for pointers to `const` as
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct iterator_traits<const T*> {
>   typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
>   typedef T value_type;
>   typedef const T* pointer;
>   typedef const T& reference;
>   typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
> };
> ```

So there's no point to providing your own `std::iterator_traits<char*>` specialization.  Since `char*` is not a user-defined type, it's also undefined behavior according to the standard.  §17.4.3.1/1 says:

> It is undefined for a C + + program to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or namespaces
>   within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add template specializations for any
>   standard library template to namespace `std`. Such a specialization (complete or partial) of a standard
>   library template results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined name of
>   external linkage and unless the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.<sup>163)</sup>
>
> 163) Any library code that instantiates other library templates must be prepared to work adequately with any user-supplied specialization
>   that meets the minimum requirements of the Standard

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you're allowed to specialise things from the standard library.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: I am quite sure specializing *for user defined types* is the only thing you are allowed to do in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I agree with @DavidRodríguez-dribeas. More precisely: 17.4.3.1 "A program may add template specializations for any
standard library template to namespace std. Such a specialization (complete or partial) of a standard
library template results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined name of
external linkage and unless the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template."

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ... which makes code from original question UB.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Oh, right, I had misunderstood that the code was in a different header of the implementation, not a user header. You are right, it is undefined behavior, and the best you can get is a compiler error... the alternative is a violation of the ODR that would be much harder to debug

Comment: Ah, well spotted -- I hadn't realized that the code was written by the OP, and not part of the library. D'oh. +1!

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth to add conclusion like "so that code is most likely workaround of deficiency of (possibly old version of) Visual C++ and should be either deleted or enclosed in `#ifdef _MSC_VER` if it's still needed in recent version."